# CSS transition animation not working for popover attribute

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, popover

While testing the new `popover` attribute, I tried to apply a transition for toggling it. This does not seem to work. Is this by design or is it a bug? The opacity is applied, but the transition is not visible.

```css
[popover] {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

[popover]:popover-open {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<button popovertarget="theonepopover">Click me to tigger the popover</button>
<div id="theonepopover" popover>Hi, I'm a popover</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to work fine if you use an `animation` instead, example:

```css
[popover] {
  animation: fadeIn 1s ease-in;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<button popovertarget="theonepopover">Click me to tigger the popover</button>
<div id="theonepopover" popover>Hi, I'm a popover</div>
```

The possibility to animate discrete properties is yet not supported, refer to [this guide](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/introducing-popover-api/#interactive-entry-and-exit) for more info. In particular:

> The ability to animate discrete properties, including animating to and
> from `display: none` and animating to and from the top layer are not yet
> available in browsers. However, they are planned for an upcoming
> version of Chromium, closely following this release.
>
> With the ability to animate discrete properties, and using
> `:popover-open` and `@starting-style`, you'll be able to set up
> before-change and after-change styles to enable smooth transitions
> when opening and closing popovers.

Updated example which uses `:popover-open` and `@starting-style` (adapted from the example in the link above, requires the `#experimental-web-platform-features` flag turned on in Chrome Canary):

```css
/* Animating */
[popover] {
  &:popover-open {
    /*   0. BEFORE-OPEN STATE   */
    /*  initial state for what we're animating *in* from  */
    @starting-style {
      opacity: 0;
    }

    /*   1. OPEN STATE   */
    /*  state when popover is open, BOTH:
        what we're transitioning *in* to 
        and transitioning *out* from */
    opacity: 1;
  }

  /*   2. AFTER-OPEN-IS-CLOSED STATE   */
  /*  initial state for what we're animating *out* to */
  opacity: 0;

  /*  enumarate transitioning properties, including display */
  transition: opacity 0.5s, display 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<button popovertarget="theonepopover">Click me to tigger the popover</button>
<div id="theonepopover" popover>Hi, I'm a popover</div>
```